# Laravel SQL Query in Eloquent?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

How would I achieve this SQL query in Laravel's eloquent?

```
"SELECT * FROM `cardfields` 
WHERE cardfields.id NOT IN (select fieldassociation.field_id 
from fieldassociation where fieldassociation.card_id = $cardid)"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `Eloquent` you need models with some relationships between the models (when models are created) but if you use [QueryBuilder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#advanced-where-clauses) then you may do it using something like this:

```
DB::table('cardfields')->whereNotIn('id', function($query) use($cardid) {
    $query->select('field_id')
          ->from('fieldassociation')
          ->where('card_id', $cardid);
})
->get();
```

Make sure you import the `DB` using `use` keyword or use `\DB` instead of `DB`.